# SQL - Realizar a remoção de duas linhas em tabelas distintas conectadas com Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Boa tarde, eu tenho uma pequena dúvida em um projeto pessoal meu.

Possuo as tabelas **pedido** e **itens_pedido** que são conectadas por chave estrangeira.

Como exemplo para simplificar a minha situação:

**Tabela pedido**

> Colunas: CODIGO(PRIMARY) & NOME

**Tabela itens_pedido**

> Colunas: CODIGO(PRIMARY) & PRODUTO_CODIGO(FOREIGN)

Agora, meu objetivo é deletar uma linha da tabela produto, que só pode ser deletada após a exclusão das linhas do **itens_produto** que se encontram conectadas pela **foreign key**. Contudo, quero deletá-la em apenas uma única SQL Query, sem ter que utilizar dois DELETE seguidos. Porém ao tentar realizar isso com o **INNER JOIN**, me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`revenda`.`itens_pedido`, CONSTRAINT `ITENS_PEDIDO` FOREIGN KEY (`PEDIDO_CODIGO`) REFERENCES `pedido` (`CODIGO`))

O erro é causado por eu tentar remover a linha da tabela **pedido** sem ter acontecido a exclusão da linha que utiliza o **CODIGO** do pedido como referência na **foreign key**.

A SQL Query que utilizei foi:

```
DELETE itens_pedido, pedido FROM pedido INNER JOIN itens_pedido ON pedido.CODIGO = itens_pedido.PEDIDO_CODIGO WHERE pedido.CODIGO = 2
```

Se alguém souber alguma forma de resolver este problema, comente aqui, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Tentou especificar `ON DELETE CASCADE` na definição da chave estrangeira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única forma de evitar o erro de violação de **Foreign Key** é desfazendo o vínculo entre os registros. Só há duas formas de se fazer:

1. Excluindo primeiro os registros filhos:

```sql
DELETE FROM itens_pedido WHERE PEDIDO_CODIGO = 2;
DELETE FROM pedido WHERE codigo = 2;
```

2. Usando a opção `DELETE CASCADE` na definição da Foreign Key. Dessa forma, os registros da tabela **itens_pedido** serão excluído automaticamente quando o registro da tabela **pedido** for excluído.

```sql
ALTER TABLE itens_pedido ADD CONSTRAINT fk_itenspedido_pedido (PEDIDO_CODIGO) 
        references pedido(CODIGO) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```